# Teradata SQL - Syntax to spool varchar for CASE OF DATA

Tags: sql, teradata, uppercase

I have a `VARCHAR(10)` column where values can be stored as 'Abxxx' and 'abxxx'

When grouping on this field (`Column1`) they are all returning as uppercase 'Abxxx' even when there are lower case values 'abxxx' in the data.

What syntax can I use to return unique data values in separate rows in the spool?

Read only access.

```
SELECT
    Column1, COUNT(unique_id)
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY 
    Column1
```

Desired result:

```
Abxxx 345    abxxx 5678
```

Comment: Try sticking `(CASESPECIFIC)` after the field in the `GROUP BY` clause. That's in Teradata. You have this tagged as Oracle as well. Perhaps you should remove that.

Comment: Updated. Throwing off the select statement, telling me it's non-aggregate @JNevill

Comment: My apologies. Also stick `(CASESPECIFIC)` behind the field in the `SELECT` clause as well. I just added as an answer since I was able to test this on my Teradata box and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `(CASESPECIFIC)` will get the result you want:

```
Select Column1 (CASESPECIFIC), count(unique_id)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Column1 (CASESPECIFIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to make the table column case specific, see below.

```
-- Create a table with one column case-insensitive, another column case-sensitive
   CREATE TABLE cities
   (
      name VARCHAR(80) NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      name2 VARCHAR(80) CASESPECIFIC
   );

   -- Insert a row
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('San Diego', 'San Diego');

   -- Name column is case-insensitive
   SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name = 'SAN DIEGO';
   -- Output: San Diego

   -- Name2 column is case-sensitive
   SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name2 = 'SAN DIEGO';
   -- No rows found
```